# What are the commands to display a numbered list of the files in a directory?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to print a numbered list of the file names in a directory.

I tried

```
dir /w > test.txt
```

What are the commands to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set num=0
    FOR %%F IN (*) DO (
        set /a num += 1
        echo !num! %%~fF
    )
    echo %num% files
endlocal
```

"%%~fF" prints the full path. To print the short filename, use "%%F". See `for /?` near the end for all possible expansions.

**Edit**: to pass in a directory, change it to

```
FOR %%F IN (%**) DO (
```

And call it with a directory name with a following slash ("C:\Windows\", not "C:\Windows"), or with no directory name.

You could also change to the directory with `pushd %*` before the for loop, and then `popd` any time after the for loop. This would be useful if you needed to do more than enumerate the files, but you want to return to the original working directory.

**Edit**: Here's a more complete, annotated version. It also lists directories -- I missed that `for` doesn't do that by default:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :: change to a dir
    pushd %*

    :: file counter
    set num=0

    :: dirs only
    FOR /D %%D IN (*) DO (
        set /a num += 1
        echo !num! %%D
    )

    :: files only
    FOR %%F IN (*) DO (
        set /a num += 1
        echo !num! %%F
    )

    :: final tally
    echo.
    echo %num% files

    :: return to original directory
    popd

endlocal
```

Simply save to a file with the extension `.cmd`, and put it somewhere in your path (eg, C:\Windows), and this should work on any recent Windows OS (tested on XP).

Comment: With the batch file , Is it possible that i can pass command line argument. E,g i make file newfile.bat and if i execute like this way

newfile.bat----  path/of/dir ---- path/of/textfile

Answer (score 0):

You can export the list of filenames using [File Names Export](http://filenames.bghot.com/download.php), place numbers, format the list in any way you want and print it out.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a small hack for this:

```
@echo off
dir /b >test.txt
find /n /v "" <test.txt
del /f /q test.txt
```

It will show like:

```
[1]file1.txt
[2]file2.txt
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one smaller hack in one line without using any variable or create any file:

- List only Name.Extension:

```
dir/b|find/n /v ""
```

- Results:

```
[1]file1.txt
[2]file2.txt
```

---

- List wirth FullPathName.Extension:

```
where .:*|find/n /v ""
```

- Results:

```
[1]c:\dir_test\file1.txt
[2]c:\dir_test\file2.txt
```

---

- For recursive:

```
dir/b/s|find/n /v ""
```

```
where /r . *|find/n /v ""
```

- Results:

```
[1]c:\dir_test\file1.txt
[2]c:\dir_test\file2.txt
[3]c:\dir_test\sub_dir\file4.txt
[4]c:\dir_test\sub_dir\file5.txt
```

---

- One edit suggest for adding lead zero adapted the **[@Anonymous](https://superuser.com/users/18451/anonymous)** answer:

You can try using this suggests getting your files/dir led by zero:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :: change to a dir
    pushd "%~dpnx1"

    echo\ & echo\:: dirs only
    
    FOR /D %%D IN (*)DO (
         set /a "_cnt_dir+=1+0"
         <con: set "_led_dir=0000!_cnt_dir!"
         <con: call echo\!_led_dir:~-5! %%~D
        )
        
    echo\ & echo\:: files only
    
    FOR %%F IN (*)DO (
         set /a "_cnt_file+=1+0"
         <con: set "_led_file=0000!_cnt_file!"
         <con: call echo\!_led_file:~-5! %%~F
        ) 
     
    echo\ & echo\::  final tally
    
    <con: echo\Total dirs !_led_dir:~-5!
    <con: echo\Total files !_led_file:~-5!
    %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1

    :: return to original directory
    popd

endlocal
```

Answer (score -1):

If using Windows with NTFS, I think this could be done with the [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) search engine. It can search for file types, with particular elements in the file name, supports regular expressions, and can export to .txt.

[image]

Comment: this is a "list of files that use numbers for names", not a "numbered list of files".

Comment: ~quack, yes, I misunderstood the last part of the question before it was revised. It was a bit ambiguous.